# Подключился в Form1 к БД MSSQL, теперь в Form2 как можно работать с тем же подключением

Tags: c#, sql-server

Подключился в Form1 к , теперь в Form2 как можно работать с тем же подключением.
Как из первой формы получить объект connection чтобы использовать во второй форме?

Comment: Объект  connection нельзя держать открытым долго. Его стоит открывать только на время совершения запроса,  и создавать каждый раз новый.  Просто подключитесь заново из второй формы,  точно так же,  как подключились из первой.

Comment: А есть Объект который можно держать дольше?

Comment: @RegularMan, зачем? Создайте такой объект себе сами, назовите его фабрика и сделайте у него метод `GetConnection`, который будет создавать и возвращать соединение.

Answer (score 0):

Лучше некогда так не делать. GUI не должен знать с какой DB он работает, между этими слоями должен быть еще как минимум Service.
Переносишь из Form1 в <Имя>Service все что связано с данными(а лучше всю логику в сервис а всю работу с данными в репозиторий, но это совсем другая история) и используешь новые методы из <Имя>Service в Form1, 2,3,4 и т.д